# Difference between rem and remu instructions in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

What is the difference between the rem and remu instructions in MIPS although both are modulo operation?

```
mnemonic  |   number of  |  operands   |   operation   
          |   operands   |             |
----------|--------------|-------------|---------------
rem       |      3       |  d, s1, s2  |   d = s1 % s2;  gives remainder
remu      |      3       |  d, s1, s2  |   d = s1 % s2;  gives remainder
```

Comment: Please also say which emulator you are using. Real MIPS CPUs don't have a `rem` or `remu` instruction. On real MIPS CPUs the `div s1,s2` and `divu s1,s2` instructions are used to compute the reminder.

Comment: In fact, when I was getting the information, i referenced the notes [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/MAL.instructions.html) and the contents of the instruction set in [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387206363?utm_campaign=3_pier05_buy_print&utm_content=en_08082017&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=google_books#aboutBook) book. I'm a little new to these issues yet, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The rem instruction's used with signed numbers.
But the remu instruction's used with unsigned numbers.